# Run fastapi / sqlalchemy endpoint directly from code

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, endpoint

I am using Fastapi and SQLalchemy.
I have PUT endpoint which calls two functions from service and each of those functions calls two repository functions.

Is there possibility to call endpoint (service/repository) functions directly from code? I mean not calling swagger url but calling directly function.

Comment: I think the easiest would be separating the endpoint logic to a separate function, and then call that from both places.